# Jest error: This promise must be present when running with -o

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-webkit, jestjs

I'm using https://github.com/naviapps/create-nw-react-app and can't run the test command (npm run test).

Here is the terminal outut:

```
Determining test suites to run...Error: This promise must be present when running with -o.
at /path/to/app/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/build/search_source.js:202:17
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at step (/path/to/app/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/build/search_source.js:19:362)
at /path/to/app/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/build/search_source.js:19:592
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at /path/to/app/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/build/search_source.js:19:273
at SearchSource.getTestPaths (/path/to/app/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/build/search_source.js:216:10)
at /path/to/app/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/build/run_jest.js:44:29
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at step (/path/to/app/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/build/run_jest.js:23:380)
```

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Node 9.2.0 and 8.9.2
Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: solved: https://github.com/naviapps/create-nw-react-app/issues/3#issuecomment-350044952